# Nuxt: How to access store in rollbar.js WITHOUT using localStorage?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, rollbar

I am using Nuxt and [Rollbar](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js). I have a user id state in store.
My question is, how can I set this user id as a custom payload in the transformer function in rollbar.js WITHOUT using localStorage?

Here is my code:

```js
// plugins/rollbar.js
const transformer = function(payload) {
  payload.user_id = user_id_from_store // how to get this from store?
}
```

```js
// store/index.js
export const state = () => ({
  userId: ''
})
export const mutations = {
  setUserId(state, userId) {
    state.userId = userId
  }
}
```

```js
//components/MyComponent.vue
methods: {
  fetch() {
    const userId = fetchUserId()
    this.$store.commit('setUserId', userId)
  }
}
```

Things I have tried:

- In rollbar.js, create and export a function which takes a context object as argument. Then call this function in transformer function to get user_id:

```js
// plugins/rollbar.js
const getUserId = context => {
  const user_id = context.store.state.userId
  return user_id
}

const transformer = function(payload) {
  payload.user_id = getUserId()
}

export default getUserId
```

When I `console.log(context.store)`in `getUserId` function, I got a Store object, but calling the function in transformer function threw `Rollbar: Error while calling custom transform() function. Removing custom transform(). TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined`.

Comment: You have access to Nuxt context in plugins: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context So you could access `store` there. If you need to set a specific value at the beginning, you can use `nuxtServerInit` https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action PS: you should not use `mutations` (`$store.commit`) to update your vuex store but rather async `actions` (`$store.dispatch`).

Comment: As for the syntax in the plugin, it's more of a `export default ({ store }) => { ... }`

Comment: Also, you should either use some `inject` here, if you want to stick with vanilla JS code: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context Or maybe give a try to the Nuxt module: https://github.com/gaelreyrol/nuxt-rollbar-module

Comment: @kissu the inject function helped me out. I wrapped my rollbar block with the inject and call it back in my component and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, OP succeeded thanks to `inject`, more info available here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context

This one is indeed needed for libraries that are not directly into the Vue ecosystem but that we wish to have working in our Nuxt app.